# Push to github from EC2 ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, amazon-ec2

when I run the following it seems successful:

```
$ sudo ssh -T git@github.com
Hi x! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

However, when I do a `sudo git push` from my repo, it doesn't work I get

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Are you sure your key is authorized for the specific repo?

Comment: how would I be able to check this? I mean i created the repo myself on a mac, then cloned the repo in an ubuntu instance. Now I'm trying to push from the ubuntu instance.

Comment: Hm, I think I might know the issue. It probably has something to do with my .git/config?

Comment: not sure. if the key is okay you should be good. why do you sudo for ssh stuff, btw?

Comment: It's the only way that I can get permissions ~/ isn't letting me do anything. Either way the .pub key is in the right place so not sure it matters?

Comment: Have you read this section of the github FAQ about ssh? it has some warning re using sudo and git. http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/

Answer (score 0):

The facts that you are running that on EC2 shouldn't matter at all. You are facing here an issue of an incorrect setup of ssh key and/or initially cloning the repo with the wrong user.

Whatever you do, there should be absolutely no need to use sudo. You should be able to clone the repo using an ordinary user. If that doesn't work, make sure to generate a new ssh key for this user and add it to the repo. If

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

is working again for this user, try to clone the repo again. If that works, check if you can push to it.

If you are still running into problems, make sure you followed the [install guide for Linux provided by GitHub](http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/). Everything written there works also on an Ubuntu version without graphical frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue on my AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance and I just ended up solving it with a push in the right direction from this [blog post](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2010/12/28/permission-denied-publickey-with-git-on-ubuntu/).

What was happening for me was that `root` had access to the folder I was trying to clone into.

`drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 25 00:51 sites`

Because of that, I had to do a `sudo git clone ...` command because I didn't have write permissions to that folder as my default user.

All I needed to do was give myself write access to the /sites folder

`sudo chown -R ubuntu /sites`

Which allowed me to omit the sudo in the `git clone...` command, which ran the git command as the user `ubuntu`.

This fixed it for me, and I think it's cause the files in my `~/.ssh` folder were owned by `ubuntu`, and it had to be that user running the command.